# Can Lua's require function return multiple results?

Tags: lua

It is possible to create a Lua module which returns multiple results via the require function? I'm currently writing an extension to package.loaders and I want to know if I need to support such behavior.

For example, take the following module, named `mod.lua`:

```
print("module loading")
return "string1", "string2"
```

Which is required by the following script:

```
print("running script")
s1, s2 = require("mod")
print("s1: " .. tostring(s1))
print("s2: " .. tostring(s2))
```

Results in the following output:

```
running script
module loading
s1: string1
s2: nil
```

When I would expect the second string to be returned. I'm not looking to use such behavior, and I realise that you could replicate it by returning a table and unpacking that, I just want to know if it's meant to work (as it's valid Lua syntax) and I can't find a definitive answer on this anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lua 5.1.3
`require` lua export implemented in `static int ll_require (lua_State *L)` in `loadlib.c` file. This functions always returns 1 as number of returned values on stack.

Comment: Yeah, it looks that way looking at the source (I'm on Lua 5.2 and it's the same single return value). I guess the restriction is partly because it stores the result in `_LOADED["mod"]` and it wouldn't be able to return multiple values from there without packing them in a table and unpacking them again which is unnecessary in most cases.

Comment: @GooseSerbus It's also because `require` modifies the return value.  If the module returns `nil`, `require` returns `true` instead.

Answer (score 16):

You could always return a function from your module and have that return multiple values, like below:

foo.lua

```
return function() return "abc", 123 end
```

bar.lua

```
local a, b = require "foo" ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may be preferable to pass-back a 'table' if entries, depending on what you need to return.

---

--  -- -- -- -- **Parent.Lua** -- -- -- -- --

```
local ChildReturns=require("Child");
print("The favourite toy is "..ChildReturns.GetFavourieToy());
print("List ALL toys on the child's favourites list:-");
for F_vK,F_vV in ipairs(ChildReturns) do
   print(F_vK,F_vV);
end
```

--  -- -- -- -- **Parent.Lua** -- -- -- -- --

```
local ChildReturns=require("Child");
print("The favourite toy is "..ChildReturns.GetFavourieToy());
print("List ALL toys on the child's favourites list:-");
for F_vK,F_vV in ipairs(ChildReturns) do
    print(F_vK,F_vV);
end
```

== == == ==

```
The favourite toy is Lego
List ALL toys on the child's favourites list:-
1       Lego
2       Meccano
```

And if needed one could even use the 'unpack' command.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it:

foo.lua

```
return {val1, val2}
```

bar.lua

```
myval1, myval2 = unpack(require('foo'))
```

for you it might be `table.unpack`, not sure

returning a function is also nifty, but I think `upack(require())` tells you exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

When a required Lua script returns multiple results in a table like...

```
-- req.lua
return {one = 1, two = 2, three = 3}
```

...then you can catch one of them with...

```
print(require('req').two) -- Output is: 2
```

Because only the first return value goes into package.loaded.req.
Therefore multiple results that are not in a table doesnt make much sense for a script thats designed for `require()`.